# Bandwidth IP tracking

Tags: ubuntu, ip, tracking, bandwidth

I have an FTP server running Ubuntu where multiple clients connect to in order to download data. Some clients pull data once or twice per day but others pull data every minute or so. I'm trying to figure how much data each client is pulling in a given day or month. I have used vnstat and iftop but these tools seems to only track the live data traffic. I have also tried other tools that will track the amount of data in a given day/month but it didn't break the data usage for individual IP addresses.

Eventually I'm looking to end up with the following table.

Data Usage / month
Client 1 IP x.x.x.x 3.23 GB
Client 2 IP x.x.x.x 1.2 GB
... and so on

I appreciate your help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at  `ntop`.

> ntop is a simple,
>   free, portable traffic measurement and monitoring tool, which supports various
>   management activities, including network optimization and planning, and detection of
>   network security violations

For Ubuntu see: [ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1660244)

ntop website, there are also GUIs: [www.ntop.org](http://www.ntop.org)

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. It was a breeze to install and use. I love the GUI interface as well. Thank you Arman.

Comment: @DaviD. I'm glad that I could help you.